# Trying to Get all the dictionaries as an output

Tags: python, list, api, dictionary, flask

I'm working on a project  (a  search column sort of thing,  but for cosmetics), and I need to get all the dictionaries in the list as an output. It's similar to getting different answers in a search result. So far, I can only get out one dictionary.
Any help on how to output more dictionaries will be Nice. Thank you.
It's a list with multiple dictionaries.

```
  parameters = {
    "product_type": "lipstick"
}
response = requests.get(MY_API, json=parameters)
response.raise_for_status()
data = response.json()

for item in data:
    brand = item["brand"]
    name = item["name"]
    price = item["price"]
    description = item['description']
    product_link = item["product_link"]
    website_link = item["website_link"]
    tags = item["tag_list"]
```

Comment: What do you want to output the dictionaries to?

Right now your code just overwrites the same variable with values from each dictionary. Do you want just those parts of the dictionary in a new list of dictionaries? Do you want a dictionary of dictionaries?

Comment: I want to output it on a website using flask.  I want those parts of the dictionary to come up when a user searches for a particular product.

Comment: I think that makes this a flask question more than anything. I  added that to the tags. You may also want to clarify that in your question and show some attempt at outputting to flask in your sample code.

I haven't used flask before so I'm not  sure where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a python list of dictionaries.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp

```
  parameters = {
  "product_type": "lipstick"
  }
  response = requests.get(MY_API, json=parameters)
  response.raise_for_status()
  data = response.json()
  product_list = []
  for item in data:
      product_list.append(dict(brand=item["brand"],
           name=item["name"],
           price=item["price"],
           description=item['description'],
           product_link=item["product_link"],
           website_link=item["website_link"],
           tags=item["tag_list"]))
  print(product_list)
```

Comment: I believe you need a comma separating your dict items.